# Xamarin : iOS simulator : the selected execution mode is not supported for .net projects

Tags: xamarin.forms

I've just installed Visual Studio on my Mac and started my first Xamarin Forms project. I've clicked "Getting Started" for my HelloWorld, and tried to run in the iOS simulator and got the following error :

the selected execution mode is not supported for .net projects

Could anyone please explain to me why this problem appears and how to open the simulator? Android simulator works just fine.

Comment: check the Xamarin requirement- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/get-started/requirements#mac

Comment: I figured it out, thank you for the reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those having similar issues, it seems as though the Getting Started doesn’t quite work well on Mac.

Instead of using it to open the simulators, simply right click your project and run from simulator there instead.

Comment: Could you please explicit when you say "right click on your project and run from simulator" ?